# Set FFmpeg path for scikit-video outside python

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg

Is it possible to set the path of ffmpeg for scikit-video module? I know I can set using `skvideo.setFFmpegPath(path)`. Is there any environment variable that I can set, so that everytime I import `skvideo.io`, it picks the defined path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

skvideo does not directly support taking the ffmpeg path from an environment variable.  But you can adjust the system search path by setting the PATH environment variable:

```
$ export PATH=/my_path_to_ffmpeg:$PATH
$ my_script_using_skvideo.py
```